# How to call linear gradient function in typescript?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular8

I'm trying to add a linear gradient to a style variable in typescript. Something like this

in component.html

```
<div class="colored" [ngStyle]="colorTest3">
```

in component.ts

```
colorTest3 = {
   background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow)
}
```

but it keeps giving me an error. Help?

Comment: Add class colortest3 and add stylesheet in scss file not in ts file

Comment: Can you include the error message in the question?

Comment: @SHUBHAMSINGH i want to dynamically change the variable later it's not going to stay static

Comment: @ConnorsFan I think you can't put dash in typescript , i tried this `backgroundImage: linearGradient(red, yellow)`  but it says **Cannot find name 'linearGradient'**

Comment: @Ruba suppose you want red gradient then add class red , if you want green then add green class etc. And add all css in scss file

Comment: @RubaSbeih Check my answer, I have modified it to show how to use variables color1 and color2

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have a dash (`-`) in an object property name if you don't surround it in quotes. Also the value must be a string as well.

```
colorTest3 = {
  "background-image": "linear-gradient(red, yellow);"
}
```

Comment: it worked, but what if i wanted there to be variables in the function like this ` `color1="blue";

  color2="yellow";

  colorTest3={
    background-image: linear-gradient(color1, color2)
  }`

Comment: @RubaSbeih `\`linear-gradient(${value1}, ${value2})\``

Answer (score 1):

For `<div>` tag you have to add height style to show the effect of linear gradient style. and also make sure you end your div tag. (`</div>`)

in component.html

```
<div class="colored" [ngStyle]="colorTest3">
</div>
```

in component.ts

```
colorTest3 = {
    'background-image': 'linear-gradient(red, yellow)',
    'height': '200px'
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only one style to bind, you can use `[style.backgroundImage]` also you should add `linear-gradient(red, yellow)` within a `''` like this `"'linear-gradient(red, yellow)'"`

Try like this:

```
<div class="colored" [style.backgroundImage]="'linear-gradient(red, yellow)'">
```

To have dynamic colors, try like this:

```
[style.backgroundImage]="'linear-gradient(' + color1 + ', ' + color2 + ')'"
```

TS:

```
color1 = 'red'
color2 = 'blue'
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
colorTest3 = {
  'background-image': 'linear-gradient(red, yellow)'
 }
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a9oxev)

Answer (score 0):

for html:

```html
<div [ngStyle]="background"></div>
```

for ts:

```js
background: any = "linear-gradient('color1', 'color2')"
```